# How to get fragment viewModel's data from activity in Android

Tags: android, mvvm, android-lifecycle

I'm building an android app using MVVM pattern. And I want to know how to get fragment's ViewModel's data from activity.

For example, there is an activity that shows selected items. And the activity has a fragment that has items that the user can choose. And there is a ViewModel belongs to the fragment that saves the selected items.

In this case, How can I get items from fragment's ViewModel in the activity?

The solution I thought is to make a kotlin object file that helps to share items.

The activity observes the object and fragment's ViewModel set the object's data.

Is this solution, okay?

sorry for my English and thanks for your answer

Comment: Have you read the [docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#implement)?

Comment: @Lucho My question was so stupid. I should have read google docs. thanks for your answer